# Can't add a record to the form, I get the error 'you can't go to the specified record'. (MS Access 2007-2016)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to MS Access and I'm trying to add a record to a form, where whenever I click on the 'Add Record' button, I keep getting an error - 'Can't go to specified record' which prevents me from using the button.
The form was created using a query, which links four tables together.
I've heard that I need to make the query editable, but I'm not sure as to how I would do that.
(This is what the query's SQL looks like - auto-generated by MS Access).

```
SELECT tblCustomers.Forename, tblCustomers.Surname, tblCustomers.Telephone, tblCustomers.[Customer ID], Count(tblTickets.[Ticket Number]) AS [CountOfTicket Number], 
tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID], Sum(tblTickets.[Ticket Cost]) AS [SumOfTicket Cost], 
tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID], tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type], tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID], tblTickets.[Ticket Cost], tblTickets.[Ticket Number] 
FROM ((tblCustomerTypes INNER JOIN tblCustomers ON tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID] = tblCustomers.[Customer Type ID]) 
INNER JOIN tblTickets ON tblCustomers.[Customer ID] = tblTickets.[Customer ID]) INNER JOIN tblTicketTypes ON tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID] = tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID] 
GROUP BY tblCustomers.Forename, tblCustomers.Surname, tblCustomers.Telephone, tblCustomers.[Customer ID], tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID], 
tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID], tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type], tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID], tblTickets.[Ticket Cost], tblTickets.[Ticket Number];
```

This is where the issue occurs, whenever I try to add new records:
[image]

[image]

The picture above is the relationships diagram between the four tables, along with collection of data below it.

The data below is for each respective table:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the query which combines the four tables:
[image]

Comment: Customarily a form is used to enter/edit data for a single table. Try binding form to table instead of a query. A GROUP BY query cannot be edited anyway and that means cannot create new record.

Comment: Why do you want to edit an aggregate query which is summary of data? Usually you wan to edit unit level data before it is summarized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a form to allow additions (i.e., add new record), the form must be an editable record source. However, your query record source is an aggregate query where you are running aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`) by groups (see `GROUP BY` clause). Since aggregate queries depend on underlying data to furnish results, you cannot update that underlying data on the aggregate output itself. Consequently, forms/reports based on aggregate queries are not editable.

```sql
SELECT tblCustomers.Forename
     , tblCustomers.Surname
     , tblCustomers.Telephone
     , tblCustomers.[Customer ID]
     , tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID]
     , tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID]
     , tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type]
     , tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID]
     , tblTickets.[Ticket Cost]
     , tblTickets.[Ticket Number] 

     , COUNT(tblTickets.[Ticket Number]) AS [CountOfTicket Number]
     , SUM(tblTickets.[Ticket Cost]) AS [SumOfTicket Cost]

FROM ((tblCustomerTypes
INNER JOIN tblCustomers 
   ON tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID] = tblCustomers.[Customer Type ID]) 
INNER JOIN tblTickets 
   ON tblCustomers.[Customer ID] = tblTickets.[c]) 
INNER JOIN tblTicketTypes 
   ON tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID] = tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID] 

GROUP BY tblCustomers.Forename
       , tblCustomers.Surname
       , tblCustomers.Telephone
       , tblCustomers.[Customer ID]
       , tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID]
       , tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID]
       , tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type]
       , tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID]
       , tblTickets.[Ticket Cost]
       , tblTickets.[Ticket Number];
```

---

MS Access does allow some `JOIN` queries to be editable depending on setup. So simply remove the aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`) and `GROUP BY` to return to unit level data. To test if query is not [read-only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html), run it in query design and see if you can edit any value in any column (except autonumbers) of outputted results. Even scroll to the bottom and check if you can add a record.

```sql
SELECT tblCustomers.Forename
     , tblCustomers.Surname
     , tblCustomers.Telephone
     , tblCustomers.[Customer ID]
     , tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID]
     , tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID]
     , tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type]
     , tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID]
     , tblTickets.[Ticket Cost]
     , tblTickets.[Ticket Number] 

FROM ((tblCustomerTypes
INNER JOIN tblCustomers 
   ON tblCustomerTypes.[Customer Type ID] = tblCustomers.[Customer Type ID]) 
INNER JOIN tblTickets 
   ON tblCustomers.[Customer ID] = tblTickets.[Customer ID]) 
INNER JOIN tblTicketTypes 
   ON tblTickets.[Ticket Type ID] = tblTicketTypes.[Ticket Type ID]
```

---

However, usually in MS Access design, you want to separate form entry much like normalized tables. Using above `JOIN` query, you expect the user to enter *all* customers and their types and *all* their corresponding tickets and those ticket types on a *single* form!

Consider a different, digestable approach:

1. Have the user enter all information of the customer on one form.

   ```
   Record source: tblCustomers
   ```
2. Use a combobox for `[Customer Type]`. In MS Acccess, [comboxboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox) can show human values to users but hides and stores the corresponding primary key.
3. Then on a different form or subform, enter all tickets.

   ```
   Record source: tblTickets
   ```

   - If a different form, use a combo box for `[Customer ID]` field to select from existing customers.
   - If a subform of customers main form, `[Customer ID]` is implicitly added with new entries to tickets subform.
4. Use a combobox for `[Ticket Type]`.
5. Then run your aggregate query to view results *only* and not edit data!

Answer (score 1):

To allow editing of a form?

You base the form ON ONE TABLE. And in fact in MOST cases you don't use a query for that form. Given your screen shot - you only editing values and columns from the one form anyway.

If you need to include, edit, see, have data from a child related table?

Then close the form you were just working on (the one based on ONE table - NOT a query0.

You now create a new form for say the child table. Again, that form is based on ONE table (not a query). This form will display the child data information.

Once you have that form looking all nice?

Then go back to the "main" form, design mode, and then from the side nav pane, you drag + drop in the "child" form. This will then become a sub form.

So, you this will have a main form, and for details or repeating data (child tables) you simply drop in a form (that becomes a sub form).

So you might have a main form like this:

[image]

The above has no SQL no query - just a form based on the ONE table.

But lets say I want to display a child table of "tour" booking options.

Ok, we create that form separate and base it on the child table.

And I am NOT limited to a form view. You can choose a data sheet, or better yet a multiple items form (they all work the same). After I create that form, then I go back to the main form, desing mode, and now drop in the child form.

I now get this:

[image]

And say I wanted to display the people booked in the room?

Well, once again, I go off, create a form, and AGAIN based on a single table.

And now I can drop that form into the above form.

So, now we have say this:

[image]

So, I did not actually write ANY sql. Each part of the form that is to display related (child table) information is simply another 100% separate form that I created.

I then simply dropped those additional forms into that one main form based on the main top most record.

So, where you gone wrong?

You base the form on a table. And NOT a query.

And if for some strange reason you do need or use a query for a form? AGAIN it is to be based on one table.

So that top form (a sub form) displays the people booked in the room.
The rest of the form is the booking.

And then on the bottom part I drop in the table (and from) that displays the booking options.

Access will automatic pull the child records if you setup your relationships for you.